# The Status of the Deuterocanonical Books

Tags: history

I was wondering to what degree, if any, the Deuterocanonical books of the Septuagint are used in Judaism? I could not find a good answer on this anywhere.

Obviously, the books get used in histories of Judaism, as primary sources on religious concerns during the Second Temple period. I didn't know if they ever played a role in actual religious discourse though. In general, Protestant Christians reject classifying these books as "Holy Scripture," but they do often get cited in clarifying religious points, and I figured a similar situation might exist in Judaism since the Hanukkah story is laid out in the books of the Maccabees.

Also, I seem to recall reading that at least some of these were cited in the Targum, but I haven't been able to find that again.

I suppose I'd have a similar question on the Books of Enoch, which weren't in the Septuagint.

Comment: The Septuagint in its current form is purely a Church invention and has no relation to Judaism or the Jewish Bible. The original Septuagint was just of the Five Books of Moses, and it was lost. See Rabbi Tovia Singer discuss it [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=EJRzRhZFE8o).

Answer (score 3):

Among the Apocrypha, the Book of Ecclesiasticus, or The Wisdom of Ben Sira, is used in Jewish sources.  It is quoted by name in the Talmud 17 times, in the Midrash Rabbah 8 times, and in the Zohar once.  For example, the Talmud says:

> It is written in the Book of Ben Sira [Ecclesiasticus 3:21-2] “Do not seek things that are too hard for you, and do not search things that are hidden from you.  Think about the things that have been permitted to you.  You have no need of the things that are secret.” [Ḥagigah 13a]

The Sanhedrin excluded it from the Tanakh because it shows Epicurean and Sadducean tendencies.  However, the Talmud says:

> Rabbi Yosef said: [We may ban the book as a whole, yet still] we may expound to [the masses] the good things that the book contains. [Sanhedrin 100b; also Bava Kamma 92b]

Nevertheless, the Midrash says:

> And furthermore, my son, be admonished: There is no end to making many books, [but] whoever brings into his house more than the twenty-four books [of the Bible] introduces confusion into his house, as, for example, the book of Ben Sira and the book of Ben Tagla. [The latter is lost.] [Ecclesiastes Rabbah 12:11]

Comment: Thanks so much!